# Typoglycemia generator

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to create a "typoglycemia generator" using HTML CSS JS.

I.e. A web App which takes the user input and mixes up the letters of each word except for the first and last letter.

For example: USER INPUT = "Hello everyone at stackoverflow"; OUTPUT = "Hlelo eevrnyoe at satckoeovrflw"!

I am new to JS, can anyone guide me as to what the steps would be to create this JS code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to start with javascript. You should write down the steps to do it by hand and then see how to extrapolate that into code.

Comment: Being new to a language does not mean others should be expected to do all the work for you.  What that *does* mean is you have the opportunity to learn a whole new language.

Comment: Taplar. I did not request a code to copy and paste. I clearly requested guidance to take me through the process of taking an idea and breaking it down. I am trying to LEARN JavaScript!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Detailed explanation after snippet.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

function Typoglycemia(word) {
  var letters=word.split("");
  var first=letters.shift();
  var last=letters.pop();
  var shuffled=shuffle(letters);
  shuffled.push(last);
  shuffled.unshift(first);
  var typoglycemia=shuffled.join("");
  return typoglycemia;
}

function TypoglycemiaWord(word) {
  document.getElementById("sTypoglycemiaWord").innerText = Typoglycemia(word);
}

function TypoglycemiaSentence(sentence) {
  var words=sentence.split(" ");
  var typoglycemias=words.map(word=>Typoglycemia(word));
  document.getElementById("sTypoglycemiaSentence").innerText = typoglycemias.join(" ");
}
```

```html
Enter a word: <input onchange="TypoglycemiaWord(this.value)"><br>
Typoglycemia: <span id="sTypoglycemiaWord">result here</span><br>
<br>
Enter a sentence: <input onchange="TypoglycemiaSentence(this.value)"><br>
Typoglycemia: <span id="sTypoglycemiaSentence">result here</span>
```

First thing we do is remove and save first and last letters.
It's done in `function Typoglycemia` that takes a `word` as it's parameter.
We `split` that `word` into `letters` by telling `split` to `split` every time it sees `""` = nothing = just split.
`shift` removes the first element of an Array - we store that in `first`.
`pop` removes the last element of an Array - we store that in `last`.
We need a shuffling function - `function shuffle` - that takes an Array - `array` as it's parameter.
It goes from last element back to the second - Arrays are zero-indexed, so back to index 1, which is one after index 0 = the first element.
It randomly swaps, goes back, until done, and `return`s a `shuffle`d `array`.
Back to `Typoglycemia` `function`:
We add `last` back to the end using `push`, and `first` back to the beginning using `unshift`.
Lastly, we `join` the array with no spaces `""` and `return` it.
The rest, for word, is simpler HTML and JavaScript.

For sentences, we `split` by spaced `" "`, `map` each `word` to it's `Typoglycemia`d value, and then `join` the result with a space `" "` between each `word`.
The rest, for sentence, is simpler HTML and JavaScript.

The rest: Hitting `ENTER` in an `input` element calls a function, passing to it the `value` of itself (`this`).
`TypoglycemiaWord` and `TypoglycemiaSentence` do what they do (as explained above), and send the result to a `span` element that is found by using it's `id` in `document.getElementById`, by setting it's `innerText` to that result.

Hope this was fun as it was educational!

Comment: It is often commented on questions like this that "stackoverflow is not a coding service" — questions like this _should not_ be answered. In any case, an "answer" that consists only of a code dump is not a _good_ answer, whether or not the code is good. A good answer will _teach_ the reader so they can do it themselves next time, not just hand out a solution. _"Give a man a fish, you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"._ The purpose of Stackoverflow is to teach, not to hand out fish.

Comment: @StephenP, you are correct!
However, as in real life, first I find a solution that works so I'll have something to explain, then, well, I explain the best I can.
Perhaps I could do this off-site and only produce the final result - will consider that - that will reduce dramatically the quick-to-snap responses because the don't know I'm not done yet...
It's just simpler to code here in the snippets...
I'm sure you understand.

Comment: Thank you so much iAmOren! I totally do not intend to just copy paste any code, rather I want to learn JS and you helped me a lot. I just had to see how I'm supposed to break down the code, and iAmOren did that amazingly! Thank you for your time and work

Comment: @beginnerJavaScript, Happy to help!  Thank you!

Comment: @iAmOren — I understand, it's part of the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/138482). I run into it myself when trying to post a good answer and being beaten to it because of the amount of time I spend writing my answer. (so I've upvoted your expanded answer even though the question was closed, but there were already two downvotes.)

Comment: @StephenP, thank you!